# setting a checkbox as selected when loading from code behind

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am loading the checkboxlist's listitems in the code behind as follows;

```
'load the fuel types into the checklist box
    For Each newitem As String In GetFuelTypes(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath & "OtherDataFiles\dataXML.xml")
        cblFuelstoDisplay.Items.Add(New ListItem(newitem))
    Next
```

I use the following jquery to change the css style when an item is checked;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("#cbxarea").on("change", ":checkbox", function () {
              $(this).siblings("label").toggleClass("checkboxselected", $(this).is(":checked"));

          });              
      });
```

and that works perfectly fine.BUT, I set the first checkboxlist item as selected in the aspx codebehind and you CANNOT set the css style there. How do I change the style on page load in jquery after the doc.ready?
I tried adding this to the script but it did not work

```
$("#cbxarea:checkbox").each(function () {
              if( $(this).is(":checked")) {
                  $(this).toggleClass("checkboxselected");
              }
          });
```

Here is the checkbox markup

```
 <fieldset style="height:140px;">
                <legend>Select a Fuel Type to Display</legend> 
                <div id="cbxarea" class="checkbox">
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblFuelstoDisplay" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" >              
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </div>              
            </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use space between the selectors, also you are not selecting sibling label elements.

```
$("#cbxarea input[type=checkbox]:checked")
                             .siblings('label')
                             .addClass("checkboxselected");
```

You can also trigger the change event:

```
$("#cbxarea").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function() {
    $(this).siblings("label").toggleClass("checkboxselected", this.checked);
}).change();
```

Note that if your checkboxes are static there is no need to use event delegation.

```
$("#cbxarea input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {  }).change();
```

Comment: Top suggestion does what I was looking for. Thank you, will mark as answer when able